# GAN outputting noise after training

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

So, I set out to train a gan on generating cat/dog photos, from kaggle's cats vs dogs dataset. After hyper-parameter tuning and everything in my power I'm still getting noise as output.
This what I did:

1)I converted the images into 64*64

2)Converted them into protobuffer

3)Pushed it to the graph like:

```
def input_pipe(filenames,batch_size=32):
dataset=tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=filenames)
dataset=dataset.map(parse,num_parallel_calls=64)
dataset=dataset.shuffle(25000)
dataset=dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset=dataset.prefetch(16)
return dataset
```

4) declared the generator function like:

```
def generator(z, out_channel_dim,keep_prob,is_train=True, alpha=0.2):
with tf.variable_scope('generator'):



    fc = tf.layers.dense(z, 7*7*128, use_bias=False)

    fc = tf.reshape(fc, (-1, 7, 7, 128))
    bn0 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(fc)
    lrelu0 = tf.maximum(alpha * bn0, bn0)


    conv1 =  tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(lrelu0, 512, 2, 1, 'valid', use_bias=False)
    bn1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv1)
    lrelu1 = tf.maximum(alpha * bn1, bn1)



    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(lrelu1, 256, 3, 2, 'same', use_bias=False)
    bn2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv2)
    lrelu2 = tf.maximum(alpha * bn2, bn2)



    conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(lrelu2, 128, 3, 2, 'same')
    bn3 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv3)
    lrelu3 = tf.maximum(alpha * bn3, bn3)



    logits = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(lrelu3, 3, 3, 2, 'same')

    out = tf.tanh(logits,name='image')

    return out
```

5) then the discriminator:

```
def discriminator(images, reuse=False, alpha=0.2):

with tf.variable_scope('discriminator', reuse=reuse):


    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(images, 128, 4, 2, padding='same')
    lrelu1 = tf.maximum(alpha * conv1, conv1)


    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(lrelu1, 256, 3, 1, 'valid')
    bn2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv2)
    lrelu2 = tf.maximum(alpha * bn2, bn2)



    conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d(lrelu2,256, 2, 1, 'valid')
    bn3 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv3)
    lrelu3 = tf.maximum(alpha * bn3, bn3)



    flat = tf.layers.flatten(lrelu3)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(flat, 1)
    out = tf.sigmoid(logits)
    return out,logits
```

6) The loss function:

```
def model_loss(input_real, input_z, out_channel_dim,keep_prob, alpha=0.2, smooth_factor=0.1):
with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    d_model_real, d_logits_real = discriminator(input_real, alpha=alpha)

    d_loss_real = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=d_logits_real,labels=tf.ones_like(d_model_real) * (1 - smooth_factor)))

    input_fake = generator(input_z, out_channel_dim, keep_prob, alpha=alpha)

    d_model_fake, d_logits_fake = discriminator(input_fake, reuse=True, alpha=alpha)

    d_loss_fake = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=d_logits_fake, labels=tf.zeros_like(d_model_fake)))

    g_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=d_logits_fake, labels=tf.ones_like(d_model_fake)),name='g_loss')

    final_d_loss=tf.add(d_loss_real,d_loss_fake,name='d_loss')

    tf.summary.scalar("d_loss",final_d_loss)
    tf.summary.scalar("g_loss",g_loss)
    merged=tf.summary.merge_all()
    return final_d_loss, g_loss,input_fake,merged
```

The loss after training looks like this:
[Discriminator Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9div.png)
[Generator Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GO9t.png)

I have already tried batch_norm in input_real_image, drop-out, changing the learning rate of generator and dicriminator nothing meaningful comes out only noise.:[GAN Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlcRp.png)

Note: discriminator loss doesn't go to zero it's around 0.5 in case u wanna suggest gradient vanish

Comment: Might be mode collapse, due to discriminator being too strong too fast. You might want to add the training loop and the optimizers to your question.

Comment: it is a simple adam optimizer with a learning rate of 0.003 and if it is mode collapse then i should get same image, but all I get is noise, but it is mode as the noise that I get is always same too. I don't think the driscriminator is too strong cause loss is not not approaching zero but i'll try decreasing a few layers.